# How can I enable opcache preloading in PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, preloading, opcache, php-7.4

I'd like to enable [opcache preloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.preload) ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/preload)) on my production servers in PHP 7.4.

I'm using [Symfony 4](https://symfony.com/) if it changes anything.

Comment: Not sure how much https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/e8pgzi/weve_found_some_fundamental_design_problems_in/ will affect any plans for using it.

Comment: [Symfony on preloading](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-preloading-symfony-applications-in-php-7-4)

Comment: Check [this article](https://stitcher.io/blog/preloading-in-php-74). Also read that bug Nigel posted, as it seems quite critical for the time being.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-4-preloading-symfony-applications-in-php-7-4) this appears to be trivial. Apparently Symfony since 4.4 generates a preload script which has to be set in the `php.ini`:

```
opcache.preload=/path/to/project/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php
```

I did some tests in my local Docker environment and this is how it went:

**PHP 7.3 without OPcache (current)**

```
Requests per second:    8.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       114.402 [ms] (mean)
```

**PHP 7.4 without OPcache**

```
Requests per second:    11.44 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       87.417 [ms] (mean)
```

**PHP 7.4 with OPcache, without preloading (Apache + modphp)**

```
Requests per second:    30.25 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       33.053 [ms]
```

**PHP 7.4 with OPcache, without preloading (nginx + php fpm)**

```
Requests per second:    40.00 [#/sec] (mean)
```

Unfortunately I was not able to enable the preloading :( I encountered following errors (in both Apache+Mod and Nginx+FPM):

```
double free or corruption (!prev)
child pid 17 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump (…)
```

This feature looks like a [WIP](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/34910) though. I'm going to revalidate this answer when I'm able to use this preloading thing. In overall I'm quite impressed, +30% performance just by upgrading from PHP `7.3` to `7.4`.

Comment: I am trying preload on Symfony with fairly large size application, I am getting errors like  Cannot declare class because the name is already in use. I am using require_once in preload file to be able to load dependencies as well which probably is conflicting with loaded classes.

Comment: @vishal i've got the same issue. Did you eventually find the reason ?

Comment: Sure, upgrade PHP to the latest version.

Comment: @emix You might want to update your answer since its really great and I almost obmitted it because of the written conclusion that it does not work. Fortunately I saw your comment in time.

Comment: One day for sure ;)

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should add:

```
opcache.preload=/path/to/project/preload.php
```

to your `php.ini`

Then in your PHP script you should pass in `opcache_compile_file($file);` each file you want to preloaded.